# SQL: How to select one row per day

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-optimization

I have a database that has a row entry for every minute (86,000 values per day) and I am trying to write PHP to select only one row per day. I have a column "timestamp" that has the current timestamp in regular format (2017-12-09 06:49:02).

Does anyone know how to write a **select statement** to do what I am trying to do?

Example output:

```
2017-12-09 06:49:02, datavalue
2017-12-10 06:49:02, datavalue
2017-12-11 06:49:02, datavalue
2017-12-12 06:49:02, datavalue
```

Comment: Try using `DISTINCT` in your statement - `SELECT DISTINCT DATE(TIMESTAMP) FROM YOUR_TABLE ORDER BY DATE(TIMESTAMP);`

Comment: That is a really good idea, but I tried '$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE(`timestamp`) * FROM db";' and I got 0 results

Comment: I don't think that " * " is required in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select min(t2.timestamp) as min_timestamp
      from t t2
      group by date(t2.timestamp)
     ) t2
     on t.timestamp = t2.min_timestamp;
```

Comment: That looks great, but can you explain what "t.*" is?

Comment: @Gordon How did you know he wanted the first row of the day?

Comment: @itsLex . . . I don't.  But the first record on the day is a valid way to get one record per day.

Comment: @pclever1 . . . `t` is your table name.

Comment: Be careful, if you have two with the same timestamp you'll get multiple rows returned.  Which you don't in this case though :). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group

Comment: Explanation: You can not combine * and DISTINCT, thus if you want every field of the result you need to use a JOIN with a subselect. Inside the subselect you can ignore all fields (no *) but only use the fileds you need to identify the 'filter fields'. That way you can group that subselect without defining each and every field to select. With the ON clause you can filter out the 'preseletected' ones from t2 out of t1.